# How to work with mixed content?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml input like:

```
<root>
  <section>Start of text<link>link text</link>Back to section.</section>
</root>
```

And I hope to use xslt to get the output xml as:

```
<File>
  <para>Start of text</para>
  <para>link text</para>
  <para>Back to section.</para>
</File>
```

I'm new to xslt and have no idea how to do it. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Update: this is my current xslt looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <File>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="descendant::inner">
            <para>
                <xsl:value-of select="descendant::inner"/>
            </para>
        </xsl:if>
    </File>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:element name="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and here's the output:

```
<File>
   <para>Start of textStart of text</para>
   <para>link text</para>
</File>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just surround any non-empty descending `text()` nodes of `root` with `para` elements like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <File>
      <xsl:for-each select=".//text()">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != ''">
          <para>      
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
          </para>   
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>   
    </File>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<File>
    <para>Start of text</para>
    <para>link text</para>
    <para>Back to section.</para>
</File>
```